# How to define and use a list/array of chars using `Serial.print`

Tags: string

I wish to define a list of months names and access it when printing a report.

Array was defined as follows:

`const char months []= 
{'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'};`

```
for (int i=0; i<=11; i++) {

                                 Serial.print(months[i]);
                        }
```

**Tries:**

I was looking for help under `Arrays` in Arduino documentation didn't give, as far as I found, any explanation for such case, but arrays of `int`

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I just want to point out that Arduino uses C++. Straightforward questions like this, about how to create and access arrays can be answered by doing a C++ tutorial. There is nothing particularly special about the fact that the code is running on an Arduino.

Comment: @NickGammon - thank you for your answer. I'm aware of that, but still I did not find any explanation for such case.

Comment: Very good. *I try to define and access this list without any success* - I suggest for future questions you are more explicit about the problem. I see that I can actually **define** the array the way you did it without error, but I can see that you would have problems **printing** it because you used single quotes rather than double quotes. It helps to explain what "without success" actually means. If I said "I tried to bake a cake, without success" how would you advise me? A different recipe? A different technique? A better oven? Better ingredients?

Comment: I'll rewrite it.

Comment: @NickGammon - question is now re-written. Hope it is more undrestandable and not "off-topic"

Comment: Very good. I see that there are vote(s) to re-open the question. Most of the moderation here is done by community members, so we'll see what happens to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there:

- Use a char* instead of char, a char can only contain one character
- Use " instead of ' (Thanks Juraj)

Then you get:

```
const char* months[] =
 {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```

Comment: Just fixed :-), found this computer has Arduino installed

Comment: The timelib uses progmem and a single string for short names and multiplies the index with 3: https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time/blob/master/DateStrings.cpp

Comment: @Jot that's also possible, than you just need a function to retrieve the three characters; btw, I didn't see any different in using PROGMEM in my code, maybe it helps if it is just one string (would save 48 bytes).

Comment: `const char* regards[] ={"Thank", "you","very","much!!"};`

Comment: @Guy.D You're welcome